# How mandatory is flow control in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that I'm writing.  Within a foreach loop are a bunch of tasks.  It has a task that must be performed first, but the rest can be performed in any order.

Let's say I have "task1" which is the 1 that must be performed first within the foreach loop and then everything else can be performed whenever.

Let's say that parenthesis () stand for a container and -> stands for a precedence constraint.

Is this a valid control flow that would result in the entire package being completed, while completing task1 first?:

```
foreach(task1 -> SequenceContainer( task2  task3  task4 ))
```

or would I have to specify

```
foreach (     task2 <- task1 -> task3 
                         |
                         v
                       task4              )
```

Additionally, if this DOES work, and I have the foreach to continue to the next iteration on failure, will it skip to the next iteration immediately upon failure of a module, or will it try to complete everything before going to the next iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, SSIS will work just fine without flow control as long as the tasks don't depend on previous tasks being complete.  It allows the system to work concurrently, which can be faster.

The issue to keep in mind is that the system *is* working concurrently.  If your tasks are touching the same tables, you might end up with deadlocks, transaction waits, or unexpected results.

Comment: Ah thank you very much.  They are in fact accessing the same tables, but only in terms of inserting.  Would this matter?

Comment: @Aserian You shouldn't run into any problems with deadlocks if you're just doing inserts and there's nothing complicated going on with the table, but multiple concurrent inserts can block each other since indexes need to be updated as well as the table.  In other words, it might work just fine, but you might not see much performance increase.  Unless I saw real improvement, I'd probably keep the flow control just because that eliminates having to think about it.

Comment: Thanks!  If I decide to leave out the precedence flow constraints, and a single package failed, would the foreach think that it had failed and not complete the rest of the tasks? Or complete the rest of the tasks then fail?  The reason I want to leave the flow controls out is because I want the foreach to complete every package that it can regardless of if one fails or not.  Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @Aserian  It depends on what you have the tasks configured to do when they encounter an error.  In my packages, I generally have the entire set of tasks in a sequence container that's configured to run Serializable and to fail when an error occurs so essentially the entire package rolls back when an error happens.  In my system I'd rather have old data than bad data and data needs to be consistent, so one error is enough to stop the process.  Personally, I haven't had to do much with modifying error trapping or handling, since I just want failure to occur.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! That helps.  I might just go through and add an event handler to each package.  A little monotonous, but better error reporting and control.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence container will not report completion until all of its child tasks have reported completion.  If your subtasks are truly independent, then running them concurrently is a perfectly fine idea.